# How does this high voltage device work?

Tags: high-voltage, flyback, high-speed, resonant-converter

In Ali express, I found the following high voltage small generator for fun.
[image: img1]
One transistor, one single coil, 2 caps and 2 resistors (not sure if the leds are an essential part of the circuit). The simplicity of this circuit puzzles me (see also the other pics).
I know about very simple self resonant circuits which use a transformer (with an additional feedback wire), but I don't see how a single solenoid (which is apparently connected only at one end) is used to generate the oscillations.
I believe the idea is to use the self resonant frequency of the coil.
This topology is probably well known to many of you. Could you provide schematic and an brief explanation of the working principle. I'm just curious.

[image]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image]

Comment: Actually, I found the answer in another thread https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339770/how-does-this-tesla-coil-design-work?rq=1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this tesla coil design work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339770/how-does-this-tesla-coil-design-work)

Answer (score 2):

There is a two-turn coil made of PC trace under the white circles on top of the PCB. This acts as a transformer winding. The solenoid is the other transformer winding. One end of the solenoid is connected to the PCB: grab hold of the other to feel the effects!

I thought at first it was just a DC circuit, the high voltage appeared as a transient when you press or release the switch. I may be wrong, maybe it manages to oscillate.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a transformer, good point. Regarding the circuit, according to the images it works continuously and is able to light a small neon bulb (provided with the kit in the image). See update of the question, where I have added an image.

Comment: OK, after your comment, the answer appears now in the following thread https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339770/how-does-this-tesla-coil-design-work?rq=1

Comment: Don't "oscillate" alone really. Confirmed. Seems to only work at "powering".

Comment: No, according to all the reactions in the device product page, the device works just fine, continuously, without help to oscillate. Just to let you know.